# Form in Microsoft Access inserts into table but other form doesn't even though the code is the same

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform within a form from which I need to insert data into a table in an SQL Server database. But it doesn't. I tried inserting in the same table from another form and from it's respective subform and it worked out fine.

Let's call the subform that doesn't insert SubA and the form and subform that work FormB and SubB respectively. Although subA doesn't insert, the database somehow takes into account the insert because the id increases by 1 in the record. Let's say the latest id is 56. I try inserting from subA and nothing happens. Then I try inserting with FormB or SubB it does insert and when checking the table it shows the insert but the id is now 58 as if SubA's insertion was indeed succesful but it's not there.

(Keep in mind these are just test insertions, not the real values I have to insert, in SubA I have a textbox (txtBatchNum) that stores a number that increases by 1 after every insertion. In the other forms I assigned it manually.)

This is the insert code in SubA:

```
Private Sub Command86_Click()
    ssqls = "INSERT INTO [dbo_Depreciation] (Account, Subaccount, Anual_Dep, Month_Dep, State, Book_Value, Batch_num) VALUES (2, 4, 187244.23, 13123, 1, 700000, '" & Me.txtBatchNum.value & "' )"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL ssqls
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

This is the insert code in FormB:

```
Private Sub Command49_Click()
    ssqls = "INSERT INTO [dbo_Depreciation] (Account, Subaccount, Anual_Dep, Month_Dep, State, Book_Value, Batch_num) VALUES (6, 4, 187244.23, 13123, 1, 700000, 19 )"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL ssqls
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

This is the insert code in SubB:

```
Private Sub Command27_Click()
    ssqls = "INSERT INTO [dbo_Depreciation] (Account, Subaccount, Anual_Dep, Month_Dep, State, Book_Value, Batch_num) VALUES (6, 4, 187244.23, 13123, 1, 700000, 19 )"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL ssqls
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: If `Batch_num` is numeric, you shouldn't put quotes around the value.   `...1, 700000, " & Me.txtBatchNum.value & ")"`   There's a big difference between `'19'` and `19` ....

Comment: If Batch_num as number type field, don't use delimiters (remove the apostrophes).

Answer (score 0):

If `Batch_num` is numeric, you shouldn't put quotes around the value:

```
Private Sub Command86_Click()
    ssqls = "INSERT INTO [dbo_Depreciation] (Account, Subaccount, Anual_Dep, " & _ 
     " Month_Dep, State, Book_Value, Batch_num) VALUES" & _
     " (2, 4, 187244.23, 13123, 1, 700000, " & Me.txtBatchNum.value & ")"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL ssqls
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

There's a big difference between `'19'` and `19`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I found the problem, it was an error with the foreign key in the Batch_num column in the Depreciation table. It was dependent on another table that stored the batch numbers, and since I was trying to assign batch_number a number greater than the highest one on the Batch_numbers table, obviously it wasn't inserting anything in the Depreciation table. I deleted the foreign key and then it worked just fine. Sorry for making you waste time with my dumb mistake.